# Das Verb für Lichtstrahlen mit Muster?

Tags: single-word-request, verb-choice

Was wäre das beste Verb, um zu bezeichnen, dass Lichtstrahlen Muster erzeugen? Am einfachsten nehme ich "Lichtstrahlen schimmern", aber eigentlich wäre etwas Archaisches/Poetisches/Gehobenes passend.
**Edit:**
Das ist ein Gedicht und es gibt etwa sieben Wörter im entsprechenden Satz, aber ich kann es versuchen mit vielen Wörtern zu beschreiben:

1. Das Schloss strahlt Lichtstrahlen aus.
2. Mit diesen Lichtstrahlen werden Muster kreiert. Das sind
   Zeichnen, bei denen aber auch Farben eine Rolle spielen können. **‣**
3. Damit wird der Ruhm des Volkes verbreitet.

**‣** (2) ist das eine Wort, das Verb, das ich suche. Das heißt, eigentlich werden keine „Muster“, „Zeichen“ oder „Farben“ genannt. In meiner Sprache ist das ein Partizip – wenn das Verb „ausstrahlen“ wäre, dann wäre der Satzteil „Lichtstrahlen ausstrahlend“.
Wie wäre es also mit ***Lichtstrahlen flimmernd***?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78916/discussion-on-question-by-andra-das-verb-fur-lichtstrahlen-mit-muster).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Farb- und Lichtspiel können auf verschiedene Arten auftreten. Entsprechend sind die deutschen Verben dafür.

1. schimmern - matter Glanz, wenig Lichtausstrahlung, zeitlich wenig Veränderung (ähnlich wie leichtes glühen), geheimnisvoll. Ein See schimmert im Mondlicht.
2. flimmern - relativ intensiv, stark und schnell pulsierendes Licht. Eine Glühlampe mit Wackelkontakt flimmert.
3. funkeln - auffällige kurze Lichtreflexe erzeugend, wie plötzlich auftretende Funken, in verschiedenen Farben möglich, relativ wenig und große Lichteffekte. Das Metall eines Schwertes oder einer Rüstung funkelt im Licht.
4. glitzern - ähnlich wie funkeln, aber viel filigraner und mit mehr Lichteffektstellen. Quarzstein glitzert.
5. schillern - ständig wechselnde Licht- und Farbeffekte, aber stark auffallend bis blendend, in verschiedenen Farben möglich. Die Flügel einer Libelle schillern im Licht.

Das bezieht sich aber auf das Objekt, welches Licht aussendet. Wenn das Licht auf ein anderes Objekt fällt und diese Lichteffekte Muster auf diesem erzeugen, sagt man:
- das Licht/ die Farben malt/malen, projizieren, erzeugen Muster, zeichnen/werfen Schatten

Das alte, lettische Verb "margot" (siehe Kommentar zur Fragestellung) wird mit "bunt schimmern" übersetzt, das bedeutet: eine moderate, in Farben wechselnde, zurückhaltende, ständige Lichtveränderung.

Für das Gedicht bietet sich wahrscheinlich "funkeln" an.

Answer (score 4):

Das einzige Verb, was mir da einfällt, wäre

> projizieren (= durch Ausstrahlen von Licht Bilder auf einer Fläche entstehen lassen)

Demnach würde das Schloss Muster, die aus [farbigen] Zeichen bestehen, auf eine Fläche projizieren.

---

Die aktuelle Übersetzung des Gedichts habe ich hier gefunden:
https://lyricstranslate.com/en/gaismas-pils-das-lichtschloss.html

Es scheint um die drittletzte Strophe zu gehen.

Comment: danke, aber sorry, das muss soo gehoben sein, dass ein Wort lateinischer Herkunft gar nicht geht

Comment: @Andra was hat es mit der Herkunft eines Wortes zu tun, ob es im Kontext past? Und warum keine lateinische Wurzel? Wie definierst Du „gehoben“?

Comment: @Stephie "projizieren" im Gedicht, das kein Volkslied ist, aber sowas  ähnliches, geht nicht. Und es gibt kein Subjekt - "Muster" werden nicht genannt, also, das Verb muss irgendwie _einen Schimmer_ davon enthalten.

Comment: @Andra dein zweiter Kommentar beantwortet für mich nicht meine Fragen zum ersten.

Answer (score 0):

```
Auf dem Gipfel des Lichtberges. 
Ringsum Fichtenwälder,
In der Mitte das helle Volksschloss.
```

In der Mitte **gleissend** das Volksschloss

Gleissen heisst so sehr beschienen werden, dass man selber zum Lichtstrahler wird.

---

Bei **Irisieren** kommt Farbe hinzu. Wie bei der Iris im Auge. beim Regenbogen oder einem Oelfilm oder Perlmutt etc.

(Bin via funkeln / glitzern / Gold / gelb hier gelandet, bzw. engl. sparkle)

Comment: in der Frage geht es nicht um diese Zeile

Comment: @Andra Doch. In der OP wird vom strahlenden "Schloss" und dem Ruhm des "Volkes" gesprochen. Die drittletzte ??? Ein Neues Jerusalem wird besser mit gleissend als HELL wiedergegeben. Es ist offenbar alles die gleiche Wurzel wie GELB, GOLD, GLITZ-, CHLOR und SELEN- (Gemuese in Slaw.).

Comment: Ach...@Andra umd wieo hast Du nicht einfach den Vers als erstes gepostet? Was geht hier ab?